# Finding lengths of sides on triangles with 3 given medians and lengths

Tags: triangles, median, centroid

The medians of $△TUV$ are $\overline{TX}, \overline{UY},$ and $\overline{VW}$. They meet at a single point $Z$. In other words, $Z$ is the centroid of $△TUV$. Suppose $\overline{UY}=33$, $\overline{TZ}=8$, and $\overline{VZ}=14$. Find the lengths $\overline{ZW}, \overline{ZY},$ and $\overline{TX}$.

I'm not quite sure how to solve this type of problem so I've provided an example. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Hw? Just something that you've been curious about?

Comment: I'm just curious really. We're learning about this stuff later in the year but I'm a bit bored and want to figure it out now. I suppose to get ahead a little.

Comment: Hint: The centroid must split the median into a ratio of $2:1$. See [this](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/triangles/triangle-concurrency-points/centroid-of-triangle.php). This means that if $\overline{TZ}=8$ then $\overline{ZX}$ is either $4$ or $16$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I know how to solve similar problems when they say something like TZ= 1/3 ZW or something but I didn't have that info this time so I sought to find it.

Comment: Yes, I solved it. ZX was 4.

Comment: You solved it! That's great. You should add your answer below so we can check it over+give you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem, you only need to use a well-known fact about medians and the way the centroid divide them into ratios of 2:1. Therefore
$$\frac{\overline{VZ}}{\overline{ZW}}={\frac{14}{\overline{ZW}}}={\frac{2}{1}}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow {\overline{ZW}}=7$$
$$\frac{\overline{UZ}}{\overline{ZY}}={\frac{\overline{UY}-\overline{ZY}}{\overline{ZY}}}={\frac{33}{\overline{ZY}}-1}={\frac{2}{1}}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow {\frac{33}{\overline{ZY}}}=3\Rightarrow{\overline{ZY}}=11$$
Finally
$$\frac{\overline{TZ}}{\overline{ZX}}=\frac{8}{\overline{TX}-8}={\frac{2}{1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow{8}={2}({\overline{TX}-8})={2\overline{TX}-16}\Rightarrow\overline{TX}=\frac{8+16}{2}=12$$

There's an easy way to prove this characteristic property in regards to medians and their centroid:
[image]

Let $△ABC$ be a triangle and $D, E, F$ the midpoints of the sides $\overline{AB}, \overline{BC}$ and $\overline{CA}$ respectively. Let furthermore $\overline{FH}$ be parallel to $\overline{CD}$. Note now, that by [Thale's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) (not to be confused with another theorem with that name) in triangle $△ADC$
$$\frac{\overline{DH}}{\overline{HA}}=\frac{\overline{CF}}{\overline{FA}}=1$$
The point $H$ is hence the midpoint of the segment $\overline{AD}$, which implies
$$\frac{\overline{AH}}{\overline{AB}}={\frac{1}{4}}$$
Thus
$${\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DH}}}={\frac{2}{1}}$$
Recall now, that $\overline{FH}||\overline{GD}$. So, again, by Thale's theorem
$${\frac{\overline{BG}}{\overline{GF}}}={\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DH}}}={\frac{2}{1}}$$

Q.E.D.

PS: This property has a very interesting application in physics, where the centroid is called "center of mass of a triangle". This (very simplified) is related to the fact, that the point $D$ stays for the sum of masses of the points $A$ and $B$, so in order to balance the triangle, the point C has to be twice so separated from the center of mass than the point $D$.

Comment: Nice ......+1....