# Geometry - Proving a common centroid.

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> Triangle PQR is drawn. Through it's vertices are lines drawn which are
> parallel to the opposite sides of the triangle. The new triangle formed
> is ABC. Prove that these two triangles have a common centroid.

I started by letting $M$ be the median of $[PQ]$, and then prove that bisector of $[BC]$ from $A$ occurs at $R$ while $M$ is collinear to $[AP]$. Firstly, I'm not sure whether or not this will suffice in proving they share a common centroid, and secondly I'm not sure where to start with the proof as setting up similar triangles from the parallel lines identity has lead to nothing.

[image]

Comment: $\exists$ a homothety mapping the sides of $\Delta PQR$ to the sides of $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: I am not talking about similarity, homothety

Comment: You dont know homothety?

Comment: So what if you are in high school? I am in middle school

Comment: Okay i am trying to help you without homothety

Comment: @ShamimAkhtar  rather a lot of us have managed to get thru a math major without learning that term. It's a bit specialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$PQCR$ and $PQRB$ are parallelograms by construction, hence: $PQ=BR=RC$ and $R$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

$PRQA$ is by construction a parallelogram, hence its diagonals $PQ$ and $AR$ meet at their common midpoint $M$.

It follows that median $AR$ of triangle $ABC$ lies on the same line as median $RM$ of triangle $PQR$. The same reasoning holds for the other medians of those triangles.

Hence the medians of triangle $ABC$ meet at the same point as the medians of triangle $PQR$.

Comment: +1 Thank you, the main problem I have with geometry is not knowing whether or not the proof is complete, and if this is complete then I suppose my answer is too.

Answer (score 4):

Solution with vectors. The centroid $G$ of $ABC$ is $G = {1\over 3}(A+B+C)$

Since $R$ is a midpoint of $BC$ we have $$R = {1\over 2}(B+C)$$ and similar for $P$ and $Q$. Now the centroid $G'$ of $PRQ$ is $$G' = {1\over 3}(P+Q+R) =  {1\over 3}\Big({1\over 2}(B+C)+{1\over 2}(A+C)+ {1\over 2}(B+A)\Big) $$$$= {1\over 3}(A+B+C) = G$$

Comment: Thank you, I do feel as if the proof using a parallelogram is sufficient.

Comment: It always amazes me how a simple idea like vectors - a magnitude with a direction after all - can lead to these conclusions. [+1]!

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use this very well-known [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985004/finding-lengths-of-sides-on-triangles-with-3-given-medians-and-lengths/3003893#3003893) (look at the very end of the answer linked).

> ### Lemma 1
>
> In any given triangle $\triangle ABC$, the medians $AM_a, BM_b, CM_c$ concur at the *centroid* $S$ such that $$\frac{AS}{SM_a}=\frac{BS}{SM_b}=\frac{CS}{SM_c}=2$$

Observe now that - back to your picture -  $APRQ$ is a parallelogram and hence $M$ is the midpoint of $PQ$. Thus $S_{\triangle PQR}\in MR$ satisfies $$\fbox{$S_{\triangle PQR}R=\frac23 RM=\frac 13 AR=S_{\triangle ABC}R\implies S_{\triangle PQR}=S_{\triangle ABC}$}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\angle CQR=\angle QRP=\angle CAB$. With a same argument, it must be easy for you to derive that $AQPR$ is a parallellogram. Similarly, you can show that $BLQR, QPRC$ are parallellograms. So $BR=PQ=CR \implies R$ is the midpoint of $BC$. Similarly, $Q,P$ are the respective midpoints. And now by symmetry, you can take  half turn of the triangle $PQR$, and enlarge each of its sides by a scale factor of $2$ with respect to the centroid of $\Delta PQR$, and now this triangle will completely coincide with $ABC$, indeed implying it shares its centroid with the other triangle.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure which answer to give the check to as they both answer the question.

Comment: You can check the other answer, it is obviouslu better than mine, it uses elementary techniques.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your patience and sorry I assumed complexity in homothety but reading about it more, it seems to be very useful in projective geometry and the idea is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s is another method. Let $h$ be the homothecy of ratio $-\frac12$ centered at $G$ centroid of $\triangle ABC$. Then $h(A)=R$, $h(B)=Q$ and $h(C)=P$ thus $h(\triangle ABC)=\triangle PQR$. Since $h(G)=G$ these two triangle have the same centroid.