# Calculate coordinates of a centroid of $ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles, centroid

We have a triangle $ABC$, where on the cartesian coordinate system:

$A$ lies on $[-3, -2]$,

$B$ lies on $[1, 1]$,

$C$ lies on $[0, -6]$.

How do we calculate coordinates for the centroid of this triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to find a formula online. What you might not find that easily is the proof of this formula. So far I only know one with analytic geometry and a simpler one with vectors, so I'll present this one.

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle with centroid $S$. Denote by $D, E, F$ the midpoints of $BC, AC, AB$ respectively. Let furthermore, $O(0, 0)$ be the origin of the coordinate system.

I will only use an additional and well-known fact which I prove [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985004/finding-lengths-of-sides-on-triangles-with-3-given-medians-and-lengths/3003893#3003893): $$\color{blue}{AS=2\cdot SD}$$

---

### Vectors

Observe now that

\begin{align*}
\vec{OS}&=\vec{OA}+\vec{AS}\\
&=\vec{OA}+\color{blue}{\frac23\vec{AD}}\\
&=\vec{OA}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot \big(\vec{AC}+\frac12\vec{CB}\big)\\
&=\vec{OA}+\frac23\cdot \bigg(\vec{OC}-\vec{OA}\;+\;\frac12\big(\vec{OB}-\vec{OC}\big)\bigg)\\
&=\vec{OA}+\frac23\cdot \bigg(\frac 12\vec{OC}+\frac12\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}\bigg)\\
&=\frac13\cdot \bigg(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}\bigg)\\
&=\frac13\cdot \bigg[\begin{pmatrix}x_a\\y_a\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}x_b\\y_b\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}x_c\\y_c\end{pmatrix}\bigg]\\
&=\frac13\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_a + x_b + x_c\\y_a+y_b+y_c\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

[image]

The coordinates are thus

> $$S\bigg(\frac{x_a+x_b+x_c}3, \frac{y_a+y_b+y_c}3\bigg)$$

---

### Analityc Geometry

Define $A(x_a,y_a)$ and the points $B,C$ similarly. We, hence, have $$D\bigg(\frac{x_b+x_c}{2}, \frac{y_b+y_c}{2}\bigg)$$ from the midpoint formula. Furthermore, using $AS=2\cdot SD$, we obtain $$S\bigg(\frac13 x_a+\frac23 \cdot\frac{x_b+x_c}{2}, y_a+\frac23 \cdot\frac{y_b+y_c}{2}\bigg)\implies S\bigg(\frac{x_a+x_b+x_c}3, \frac{y_a+y_b+y_c}3\bigg)$$

Taking your values I obtained

> $$S=\bigg(-\frac23,-\frac73\bigg)$$

Comment: @dr-mathva  =  + , what's the intuition behind the first equation?

Comment: Well, vectors aren't normal segments. You can see them as a way to describe a path, i.e. vectors have a magnitude and a *direction*. Suppose you want to go walking from $O$ to $S$. You could go directly to $S$ (that's the vector $\vec{OS}$ or you could walk first to $A$ and from there to $S$ (that is $\vec{OA}+\vec{AS}$. Therefore $$\vec{OS}=\vec{OA}+\vec{OS}$$

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, the intuition seems harder than I thought. :)

Comment: I've included the analytical approach, but I guess it is more difficult to understand...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer, starting with a little Euclidean geometry before you deal with the coordinates.

> The centroid is the intersection of the medians. It is $2/3$ of the
>   way along each median from its vertex to the opposite side.

The midpoint $M$ on edge $AB$ has coordinates the average of the coordinates of $A$ and $B$. Then to travel $2/3$ of the way from the third vertex $C$ to $M$ you find the weighted average combining $1/3$ of each  coordinate of $C$ with $2/3$ of the corresponding coordinate of $M$.

You will find lots of ways to understand your question here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/medians.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The co-ordinates are,
$C :C (\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3})$

Substitute the values and you may find it!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

To at least understand the formula given in an answer, try to make a diagram of the triangle and think about it. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle) might help you.